Swift - AVAsset.duration deprecated - using the async replacement from a synchronous function
AVAsset.duration and other simple properties are being deprecated. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to change to use the async functions from a synchronous function. The old code was very simple. After loading the AVAsset, I perform some sanity checks to make sure the movie file is not corrupt, etc.  Here is the old code:
     self.duration = self.avAsset.duration
     let tracks = self.avPlayerItem.asset.tracks
     self.fps = tracks.first?.nominalFrameRate ?? 30

When I try this, the code following is depending on the values retrieved. So it seems that I need to wait for the task to complete. My brain hurts, what am I missing? Thanks in advance.
    Task
    {
        do
        {
            self.duration = try await  avAsset.load(.duration)
            self.tracks   = try await  avAsset.load(.tracks)
            self.fps      = try await  self.tracks.first?.load(.nominalFrameRate) ?? 0
        }
        catch
        {
            Globals.logger.error("MoviePlayer - loadMovie error fetching metadata")
        }
    }


Well, after sleeping on it I have a partial solution that is good enough. Instead of trying to wait for the Task to complete, I will move the sanity checks to within the Task block. This does affect my code, since the function returns a boolean for success/failure. So the result won't include the sanity checks. Good enough for now at least.

You could try moving the async mode further out. For example:
class AudioPlayer {
    func start() {
        Task {
            let success = await loadAudio()
            doSomethingElse()
        }
    }

    func loadAudio() async -> Bool {
        // ... 
        self.duration = try await ...
        return success
    }
}

